# How do I Change the format of the datepicker in ssrs to show month and year only?

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I want a datepicker in ssrs that has months and year visible.
I dont want user to choose the whole date.
Is it Possible to change the format of datepicker.

Comment: Go and check datepicker documentation

Comment: No,its not possible in SSRS report change the format of date picker.. But If you use reports in an application, you can probably use custom controls and pass their values to the report parameters.